# jqplot json_encode data not rendering line graph

Tags: json, codeigniter, jqplot

I return these 2 string from controller in codeigniter using json_encode for jqplot line grapgh

here i fetch the data

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".stats").click(function(){
        var site_id = $(this).attr("id");
       $.ajax({
        url: site_url+"statistics/fetch_stats_data/"+site_id,
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: "type=article",
        dataType: "json",
       success: function(data) {        
          stat_events_plot_graph(data['activity_events'], data['activity_tricks']);

       }
       })
     });
    });
```

plot data structure returned as php string from above ajax
[["10/21/2014 05:50",1]]

plot ticks structure returned as php string from  above ajax
[[1,"Today"]]

when i send this data to the plot the graph is not rendered

```
      function stat_events_plot_graph(activity_events_live, activity_tricks_live) { 
      var plot2 = $.jqplot('events', [activity_events_live], {
      title: 'Events',
      seriesDefaults: {
          rendererOptions: {

              smooth: false,
              animation: {
                  show: true
              }
          }
      },
      legend: { show: false },
      axes: {
          xaxis: {
              renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
              tickOptions: { formatString: '%b %#d, %#I %p',angle: -90 }

          },
          yaxis: {
              ticks : activity_tricks_live,

          }
      },
      series: [{ lineWidth: 4,
          markerOptions: { style: 'square' }

      }],
      series: [
              { label: 'Toronto' },
              { label: 'New York' }
      ],
  });
  }
```

how do I convert those 2 strings to work with the line graph ?

Comment: If the data returned is in this form `[["10/21/2014 05:50",1]]`, then strip of the first and the last closing brackets, and get it in this manner `["10/21/2014 05:50",1]`
Because, you are anyways adding a bracket when you define this: `[activity_events_live]`
Hope it helps